# Access the ListView element from within its child ListViewItems (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

How do I access a parent ListView from within one of the ListViewItems that it contains? Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Can you add some more information on what you want to do *after* accessing the listview? For example you might want to delete one of the items based on which item triggered the event .

Comment: Actually that is a great reason. But the main reason being that I want to be able to trigger a custom ItemClicked event within the custom ListView. The annoyance I have with ListView is that when SelectionMode is set to "MultiSelect", and IsItemClickEnabled is set to "true", there is no way to only trigger the SelectionChanged event when the CheckBox is checked. For example, when you click ANYWHERE on a ListViewItem, that particular item is automatically checked/selected.

Comment: Continued: I would like to select a item only when its checkbox is checked. However, when any other part of that item is clicked, I want to trigger the ItemClicked event. That way the user is able to open an item or select it with a single click. So, I cooked up my own custom ListView & ListViewItem logic to work out the problem. Well, that is my ultimate goal.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to show what you have done.

Comment: @LeBrownJones 1. Make the listview item selection mode to *Single* 2. Add a checkbox in the item template (with 2 way or one way binding based on your requirement) 3. When user checks or unchecks the checkbox, update the collection which you are using for the listview item source. Thus when user clicks on the checkbox he will be selecting the item , but when he clicks on anywhere else on the listview item, he will be triggering the selection changed event . Let me know if this helps..